# drmohundro/SWXMLHash and escaping values in Swift

Tags: swift, xml, swift4, swxmlhash

I have working on a project that handles xml responses. After a search I found a library on github [drmohundro/SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash) that works inspired on the "Swifty JSON". After a while using it, I have realised that I can't get values with escaping values.

The xml response looks like

```
let xmlResponseString = "<TrackList><Entry><Id>2</Id><Uri>/Input/E21u</Uri><Metadata><DIDL-Lite xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/"><item id="E21"><dc:title>Doing It To Death</dc:title><upnp:album>Ash & Ice</upnp:album><upnp:artist>The Kills</upnp:artist><upnp:class>object.item.audioItem.musicTrack</upnp:class><upnp:albumArtURI>http://192.168.1.106:8088/storage/emulated/0/record_cache/album_art/1535461905688.jpg</upnp:albumArtURI><res sampleFrequency="96000" bitsPerSample="24" bitrate="2304000" nrAudioChannels="2" protocolInfo="http-get:*:audio/mpeg" duration="00:04:07.431">/Input/E21</res></item></DIDL-Lite></Metadata></Entry></TrackList>"
```

In the response the album name is equal to "Ash & Ice". However the value returned is "Ash "

That is how I get the value:

```
let xmlHash = SWXMLHash.parse(xmlResponseString)
albumName = xmlHash["DIDL-Lite"]["item"]["upnp:album"].element?.text
```

Furthermore, inspecting "xmlHash" it looks like the error already comes from "SWXMLHash.parse(xmlResponseString)".

Does the "xmlResponseString" need to be escaped? 
Is it something that the library doesn't handle properly? 
Any alternative?

Thank you

**EDIT**
The response comes from another OpenHome provider device.

The original response is:

```
<TrackList>
<Entry>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Uri>/Input/E21u</Uri>
    <Metadata>&#60;DIDL-Lite xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/"&#62;&#60;item id="E21"&#62;&#60;dc:title&#62;Doing It To Death&#60;/dc:title&#62;&#60;upnp:album&#62;Ash &#38; Ice&#60;/upnp:album&#62;&#60;upnp:artist&#62;The Kills&#60;/upnp:artist&#62;&#60;upnp:class&#62;object.item.audioItem.musicTrack&#60;/upnp:class&#62;&#60;upnp:albumArtURI&#62;http://192.168.1.106:8088/storage/emulated/0/record_cache/album_art/1535461905688.jpg&#60;/upnp:albumArtURI&#62;&#60;res sampleFrequency="96000" bitsPerSample="24" bitrate="2304000" nrAudioChannels="2" protocolInfo="http-get:*:audio/mpeg" duration="00:04:07.431"&#62;/Input/E21&#60;/res&#62;&#60;/item&#62;&#60;/DIDL-Lite&#62;
    </Metadata>
</Entry>
```

According to the developer, the Metadata value has been escaped because it is an XML inside an XML. Not sure if that matter

Since I want to create an universal parse function to populate a class, I have created this method:

```
func unescapeXMLPredefinedCharacters(value:String?) -> String{

var audioString = ""

if value != nil{

    audioString = value!

    //Replace Unicode HTML Entity
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&quot;", with: "\"")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&amp;", with: "&")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&apos;", with: "'")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&lt;", with: "<")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&gt;", with: ">")


    //Replace Unicode Decimal
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#34;", with: "\"")

    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#38;", with: "&")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#39;", with: "'")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#60;", with: "<")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#62;", with: ">")


    //Replace Unicode Hex
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#x22;", with: "\"")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#x26;", with: "&")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#x27;", with: "'")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#x3c;", with: "<")
    audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#x3e;", with: ">")

}

return audioString

}
```

It doesn't know which unicode type has been used for the unescaping.

Then I get the answer from my original question

Comment: Where do you get your `xmlResponseString` from? It does not seem to be valid xml - The text node must not contain unescaped ampersands, so it's ought to be "Ash &amp; Ice".

Comment: Do you say "&" should not be there? I have edited my question

Comment: Yes, the "escaped" inner xml already is wrong in a sense that once you unescape it, a "&" appears which should be "&amp;". This "&amp;" then will be handled by the xml parser (SWXMLHash). The same holds true for other xml entities like ">" (&gt;) etc., once they are in the content of an xml text element

Comment: So, do I have to unescape the inner xml? Is the inner xml wrongly escaped (Unicode Decimal for the inner xml and Unicode HTML Entity for the inner xml entities)?

Comment: You should not unescape all those xml entities like "&amp;" or "&lt;" and you should unescape "&#38;" etc to "&amp;" rather than to "&" (also with all the others). The xml parser then will handle those "&amp;" stuff internally

Comment: Thank you. I have an answer but I you post yours I will accept it. basically what  have change is replace Unicode to HTML in unescapeXMLPredefinedCharacters function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the *escaped* inner xml already is wrong in a sense that it contains `&` characters (in unicode), and maybe `<` and others.

First, you should *not* unescape unicode entities like `&amp;` or `&lt;` at all, because the XmlParser handles this for you.

Then, you should unescape unicode entities like `&#38;` etc. into xml entities like `&amp;` (rather than to `&`), which then the xml parser will handle (see above)

Answer (score 0):

According to Andreas Answer, I have change the function

```
func unescapeXMLPredefinedCharacters(value:String?) -> String{

    var audioString = ""

    if value != nil{

        audioString = value!

        //Replace Unicode Decimal
        audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#34;", with: "&quot;")
        audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#38;", with: "&amp;")
        audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#39;", with: "&apos;")
        audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#60;", with: "&lt;")
        audioString = audioString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&#62;", with: "&gt;")

    }

    return audioString

}
```